# MariaDB v5 keeps restarting

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I have a Centos7 server, and the MariaDB server has started playing up.
Every 20 seconds or so, day and night, it restarts with no apparent error causing this.The log repeats like this:

```
Aug 13 11:16:10 instance-1 systemd: Stopping MariaDB database server...
Aug 13 11:16:13 instance-1 systemd: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Aug 13 11:16:13 instance-1 systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Aug 13 11:16:13 instance-1 mariadb-prepare-db-dir: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.
Aug 13 11:16:13 instance-1 mariadb-prepare-db-dir: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.
Aug 13 11:16:13 instance-1 mysqld_safe: 220813 11:16:13 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Aug 13 11:16:13 instance-1 mysqld_safe: 220813 11:16:13 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Aug 13 11:16:15 instance-1 systemd: Started MariaDB database server.
Aug 13 11:16:45 instance-1 systemd: Stopping MariaDB database server...
Aug 13 11:16:49 instance-1 systemd: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Aug 13 11:16:49 instance-1 systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Aug 13 11:16:49 instance-1 mariadb-prepare-db-dir: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.
Aug 13 11:16:49 instance-1 mariadb-prepare-db-dir: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.
Aug 13 11:16:49 instance-1 mysqld_safe: 220813 11:16:49 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Aug 13 11:16:49 instance-1 mysqld_safe: 220813 11:16:49 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Aug 13 11:16:51 instance-1 systemd: Started MariaDB database server.
```

cpu load i around 0.1
server memory use is about 40%
There is no swap in use.

This is making it impossible to take any database dumps as the server shuts down before completing.
Stopping http makes no difference, so even when there are no queries it is still cycling like this

Here is a bit of /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log:

```
Version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
220813 11:25:41 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
220813 11:25:41 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
220813 11:25:41  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
220813 11:25:44  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 28842439769
220813 11:25:44 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

220813 11:25:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
220813 11:25:45 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
220813 11:25:45 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.68-MariaDB) starting as process 22908 ...
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
220813 11:25:45 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
220813 11:25:45  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
220813 11:25:46 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 28842439769
220813 11:25:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
220813 11:25:46 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
220813 11:25:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
220813 11:25:46 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This shutdown was instigated by a TERM signal. This is normally done with a killall mysqld or kill $(pidof mysqld).

If you are running under systemd the TErm signal approach is also the default used in a systemctl stop mariadb.service.

Comment: I wonder what could be initiating a TERM signal on mysqld every 30 seconds.. there doesnt seem to be a cron that could be triggering this